# Using D3.select to change the thickness of text in a radial dendrogram with a mouseover

Tags: d3.js, svg, dendrogram, radial

**With assistance**, I've uncovered the way to change elements in a radial dendrogram.
The lines below perform that function.
However, I'm trying to guess at what I need to bold text with the same mouse over.  Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

// responsible for changing the style and type of the nodes when mousing over them

```
d3.selectAll('g.node').attr("id", function(d,i){ return "node"+i});
d3.selectAll('path.link').attr("id", function(d,i){ return "link"+i}); //my guess is on the line 
below
d3.selectAll('text').attr("id", function(d,i){ return "text"+i});
```

// still trying to figure out how to make the text bold on mouse over

```
   d3.selectAll('g.node').each(function(d, i) {
   d3.select('#node'+i).on("mouseover", function() { 
   d3.select('#link'+(i-1))
   .attr('style','stroke-width: 4px','style','font-weight: bold');  // my 2nd guess is on the next 
line
   d3.select('text').attr("font-weight",function(d,i) {return i*800+800;});
```

}).on("mouseout", function() {
       d3.select('#link'+(i-1)).attr('style', 'stroke-width: 1.5px','stroke-opacity: 0.4','stroke: 
    #555');
   });
   });

Answer (score 0):

In order to set `font-weight` - [which is a CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) -, `.style` should be used instead of `.attr`:

```
d3.select('#link'+(i-1))
   .style('font-weight','bold');
```

Useful reference: [modifying elements](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/#modifying-elements) with `d3-selection`.

Comment: Thank you Mehdi for reaching out.  I tried that, inserted it as suggested,

Comment: d3.select('#link'+(i-1))
    .style('font-weight','bold')
    .attr('style','stroke-width: 4px','stroke-opacity: 0.9','stroke: #000');

Comment: the `.attr('style',...` bit should be removed.

Comment: Hello Mehdi--
I wound up creating another CSS style, .node text:hover, and increased the font weight with that.  Thank so much again for responding.  Sorry I didn't see your reply earlier.

Comment: Good to know, the CSS rule is actually a very good solution, more efficient...

Answer (score 0):

(I'm still figuring how best to use this platform)

But my answer was to create a CSS class called, .node text:hover, then increase the font weight within that class.